# What is the probability of getting 'n' consecutive 1's in a 'l' bit string?(Using periodic boundary conditions)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm getting different results for $n >\frac 12$ and $n < \frac 12$. For $n\gt \frac 12$ ,it is coming to be $l*2^{n-l}$ and for $n < \frac 12$ it is $l*(2^{n-l}-1)$. I've first taken the example of 4 consecutive 1's in 10 bit string and then generalized. But I'm in doubt whether I've worked out right.Please help.`

Comment: $l$ is the length of your bit string? And the chance of getting a $1$ at any position is $\frac{1}{2}$ and independent?

Comment: Yes, 'l' is the bit string length.Yes.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is count how many sequences of length $l$ do not contain $n$ consecutive $1$'s.

To do this we use recursion, clearly $F_1=1,F_2=2\dots F_{n-1}=2^{n-1}$.

We now obtain the recursion $F_{k+n}=F_k+F_{k+1}+\dots F_{k+n-1}$ for all $k\geq 0$.

The proof is simple, there are $F_k$ sequences of length $n+k$ such that the last zero appears in position $k+1$, and $F_{k+1}$ sequences of length $n+k$ such that the last zero appears in position $k+2$ etc.

So the answer you are looking for is:

$1-\frac{F_l}{2^l}$